# Why it's not possible to play audio on 2 outputs at same time using only one audio board?

Tags: audio, audio-streaming, digital-audio

I always tried to make my computer (currently a Macbook Pro 2017) play audio on two different outputs at the same time using a single integrated audio board.

Since I was a Windows user and after that, while being a Linux user, I never could achieve that through software. I would like to know technically why it's needed a second audio board/interface in order to play a song in two different audio outputs at the same time, using a single computer with only one audio interface (i.e: earphones and computer internal speakers at the same time).

There's something related to buffers / bits problem?

Thanks

Comment: It may depend on which Mac. Some automatically switch speakers to headphones if you plug one in. That can't be bypassed, it's pretty much at hardware level. Any other 2 outputs can be used by setting up audio/midi to an aggregate device.

Comment: There shouldn't be any issues. I've done this successfully with Realtek soundcard on Windows.

Comment: Erm, just pick an audio output and add a splitter ...

Comment: That will not work if using computer internal speakers, @DavidPostill